# Granting cross-account access to S3 folder limited to specific folders per account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

My account owns a S3 bucket. I would like to provide multiple accounts access to the bucket but to only a folder in the Bucket created for them in the bucket.

```
E.g 
Account No. 1111111111 would have permissions to write to only S3://TestBucketName/1111111111/
Account No. 2222222222 would have permissions to write to only S3://TestBucketName/2222222222/
Account No. 3333333333 would have permissions to write to only S3://TestBucketName/3333333333/
```

The number of accounts will increase over time. Rather than adding a resource-policy for each account like the one shown below, is there a way to have put a placeholder in the resource-policy such that the account attempting to write an object is restricted to do so only in the folder created for that account?
My account would create the folder in the Bucket.

```
"Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowGetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::1111111111:root"
            },
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::TestBucketName/1111111111/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::TestBucketName/1111111111"
            ]
        }
    ]
```

If the folder for their account does not exist, they shouldn't be able to upload an object in the bucket.

Comment: I think it would be only possible if the other accounts were using their root user. If this was the case IAM variable `aws:userid` would hold account id. If its IAM user or role doing the requests from other accounts, `aws:userid` will hold user/role ids, not account id.

Comment: How do I provide access to the other account irrespective of the user being used to upload object in prefix location?

Comment: I'm wondering if having a role in the primary account would help. The role could be assumed by users in other accounts. Then in the bucket policy, `aws:userid` would have [form](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_variables.html) of `role-id:caller-specified-role-name`. This could simply your bucket policy to just one statement. I haven't verified that, its just an idea.

Comment: @learningMyWayThru Would the users only be uploading one file, or lots of files? How would they be interfacing with S3 (eg management console, AWS CLI, or a program/script)?

Comment: They would be uploading multiple files and would  be using S3 API / CLI

Comment: @Marcin In that case we would need to define policies to allow the other accounts to assume the role in primary account. Also, to which user/role in other accounts should the primary account gives permissions to assume the role in primary account?

Comment: @learningMyWayThru Yes, they would have to assume role before they can do anything with the bucket. So its more trouble for them, but I don't know any other way to even attempt what you want to do with the bucket policy.